# QGIS OSGEO4W Setup error

Tags: qgis, installation, osgeo4w

I uninstalled QGIS by deleting OSGEO4W folder. Then when I try to install it again using osgeo4w setup, I get this "zip.dll was not found" error message.
Does anyone have the same issue?

[image]